# How to find element from p tag

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get text from the p tag go to the  page  first  and then select the language   `english` and click on `advanced search` and then they will show you results these is the page link https://www.counselingcalifornia.com/Find-a-Therapist I am trying to extract result for `p` tag they will show me error

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.counselingcalifornia.com/Find-a-Therapist")

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[id$='IFrame_htmIFrame']")))
select = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "language_field"))))
select.select_by_value('ENG')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#searchBtn"))).click()
dunk=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']")
for dun in dunk:
    phone=dun.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@id='phoneDiv_80863']/i[@class='fa fa-phone-square']").get_text()
    print(phone)
```

Comment: You just need to remove the "/i[@class='fa fa-phone-square']" part from your xpath. Your text is in your //p tag while your locator is pointing to the telephone icon. That's why no text is coming.  Second, after click, just give enough time to load the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to selenium here. Just get the request from the url directly. And BeautifulSoup can get the `<p>` tags that have an id attribute that starts with `"phoneDiv"`. You can also alter the query to return more than 25. So here's the list of 1-100

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

limit = 100

url = f'https://www.counselingcalifornia.com/cc/cgi-bin/utilities.dll/customlist?FIRSTNAME=~&LASTNAME=~&ZIP=&DONORCLASSSTT=&_MULTIPLE_INSURANCE=&HASPHOTOFLG=&_MULTIPLE_EMPHASIS=&ETHNIC=&_MULTIPLE_LANGUAGE=ENG&QNAME=THERAPISTLIST&WMT=NONE&WNR=NONE&WHP=therapistHeader.htm&WBP=therapistList.htm&RANGE=1%2F{limit}&SORT=LASTNAME'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'row'})

for row in rows:
    p = row.find('p', {'id':re.compile('^phoneDiv')})
    print(p.text)
```

Comment: you tell me that how you generate these url

Comment: these method is superbug but I  appreciate you if you kindly that how you generate `url`

Comment: Go to Dev Tools -> Network -> Fetch/XHR. You'll see in the Headers tab the request url.